# How can i solve my shoulder pain during exercises in gym?

Tags: exercise, gym, pain, shoulders

My name is Aaron, and I'm 23 years old. I've been doing exercises for 1.5 years but I have one problem related to pain.

When I am doing exercise of biceps, my shoulder starts hurting prior to biceps pain, which means I cannot feel biceps pain. What can I do to avoid this shoulder pain? I have asked three or four gym trainers, but have not received an answer yet. The same problem is happening with my triceps and back, and sometimes with me chest. I checked my exercise position with our trainers, and with online Youtube trainers, and my position looks accurate. And I have tried low weight, e.g. 5 kg for biceps, but I still get the same pain with my shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - go, visit physical therapist. That is fastest, and best way.

Besides other advises - it would not go away by itself, so you need to stop exercising. Without help / professional treatment - it can take a month, or even longer. If you face problems with 5kg - that is serious. Also please note that simple rest is not always path to 100% recovery. At least motion range will be limited, so some physical therapy should be done.

If, for any reason you prefer to do that yourself - view [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyXq8pEoYnI) video, and test yourself. I think it is more about rotator cuff. Other option is biceps itself. Anyway - that two guys are great, and I'm using their exercises in case of problems. Much, much earlier then you are now.

If I'm right, most likely your shoulders are moved forward, which is typical this days, and brings a lot of tension to shoulders, rotators. Simple question - can you do biceps training with straight bar? If not then my guesses are more probable.

For sure I can be wrong, if your injury is with you for some time, it can be anything around - your body tries to compensate / prevent pain. So again - it is better to visit someone who saw many cases like yours...

People here are not to give medical advises. Please note that I have never see you, and just describing things from my own experience.

Comment: How can i contact to some peoples who have same problem like me

Comment: There are many potential problems, so it is really hard to say if person has same problem as yours. Sometimes diagnostic ultrasound imaging is needed. I had problem with shoulder, I know some people, but that is not enough to help someone, over Internet. That is why ppl here are so keen to close this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue likely comes from form and controlling the weight. Likelihood is you tense or lift your shoulders when curling, you should try relax everything and isolate the bicep doing preacher curls or even trying to use seated curl machines.

If these are not the solutions to your problem then it could be you have an underlying issue with your shoulder in which you should see a doctor about..

Is the pain in your shoulder muscle pain or does it feel like its locking with something else?

Comment: when i am doing bicep curl with dumbbells or barbell, that time i feel pain in back shoulder muscles.That's why there are nothing tense in bicep. Please help me. I am suffering for 1.5 years.